# Method/function throws an exception in a loop. How to continue iterating while calling this method after handling?

Tags: php, php-7.4

I have an class that has a private method. There is a loop inside this method where an exception can be thrown:

```
private function getAliasesFilters(): array
{
    $filters = ...
    $aliasesFilters = array();

    if (is_array($filters)) {
        foreach ($filters as $filter) {
            if (array_key_exists($filter['alias'], $aliasesFilters)) {
                $msg = sprintf(
                    'More than one filter with an alias "%s "was found!',
                    $filter['alias']
                );
                throw new FilterException($msg, FilterException::MULTIPLE_ALIAS);
            }

            $aliasesFilters[$filter['alias']] = $filter['filter_id'];
        }
    }

    return $aliasesFilters;
}
```

And this method is called by another method that looks like this:

```
public function getFilters(): array
{
    $filters = $this->getAliasesFilters();

    foreach ($filters as $alias => $id) {
        $filters[$alias] = new FilterDefiniton($id);
    }

    return $filters;
}
```

In other class I call `getFilters`, but I need the iteration over the error handling to continue where it left off.

The perfect way will be something like that, but it isn't possible:

```
try {
    $this->filters = $x->getFilters();
} catch (FilterException $e {
    if ($e->getCode === FilterException::MULTIPLE_ALIAS) {
        // log or something
        continue; // But this isn't iside the loop so I will get an Error ;c
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to continue iterate inside that function but with skipping this element. Unfortunately, I can't change the code of that class (the one with iteration) and I have to handle it somehow in my try and catch.

Is such a thing even possible? Every time I call this method, I get the exception in exactly the same place, and I can't skip over it.

I tried to do the method and after catching the exception, execute the method again, but it starts iteration all over again, and it throws the same exception in the same line with the same item.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd throw an exception if you want the iteration to continue.  Wouldn't it be better to log the data inconsistency inside the loop and allow it to carry on?

Comment: Because the author of this solution (This class I am calling) decided that if such a case occurs it is an "exceptional" situation and stated that throwing an exception is ideal for it.
In my use of this method, this situation is not that unique, I have to skip this element and continue.

Comment: Exceptions typically denote that an operation is unable to continue.  What you are trying to achieve isn't possible, because by the time the Exception reaches your catch statement, processing of the loop has already ceased.

Comment: As I expected. Unfortunately, this is very bad news for me because it makes me stuck. However, I was hoping that there was a "trick" to help me solve it.

Comment: Your only choices are to update that code (which you said you can't do), or possibly write your own version, possibly through a subclass if that works, otherwise duplicating. Or, find a way to change the data that gets passed into this code in the first place.

Comment: Looking at the code, `$filters = ...` has at least two items with the same value for `$filter['alias']` , can this be changed?

Comment: Not in this code, it comes from a different class (private property). and downloading from the database. Easier way to "re-write" that class but to my expectations, which is terrible

Comment: So, downloading from the database implies that the data is not correct there. Can that be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that what you want is not possible in this situation. Your solutions in my opinion is:
Your own class with functions where you will return same aliases without exception

Answer (score -1):

you must extend class and rewrite `getAliasesFilters()`